# Change "FIGURE 1:" color, but not caption color

Tags: color, captions

I would like to change the color of the "FIGURE 1:" portion of my caption to blue (including the number & colon), but I want the remainder of the caption to be black. I have tried the following in my preamble, however, the whole caption is blue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\color{blue}{FIGURE}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../ubmFigures/exampledoc}
         \caption{An example figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) provides better control over caption elements. Specifically, you can set the `labelfont` and `textfont` to include colour or not. With the elements grouped, just setting `labelfont{color=blue}` prints the `\figurename`, number and separator in blue:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{grahpicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{FIGURE}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=blue}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{An example figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

A discussion on the options are available from the [`caption` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) (section **2.3 Fonts**, p 9-10).