# Stylizing sub-figure caption in beamer

Tags: beamer, captions, subcaption

When I use

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\subfigure[Subfig 1]{
}
\hfil
\subfigure[Subfig 2]{
}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

, it gives

[image]

. Note that the font color of the figure caption and sub-figure captions are differnt. Now, how can I stylize (i.e., change color, change size, make bold, use roman numerals etc.) the sub-figure captions? I noticed that something like `\usepackage[font=normalfont, labelfont={red,bf}]{caption}` does not work with `beamer`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127354/change-figure-1-color-but-not-caption-color

-Helped me with the color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subcaption with Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125579/subcaption-with-beamer)

Comment: `\usepackage[...]{caption}` should work with `beamer`. If not, please fill out a ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I think `\usepackage[...]{ca‌​ption}` has no effect whatsoever. I'll report it. Thanks...

Comment: @pushpen.paul I just inserted `\usepackage[font=normalfont, labelfont={color=red,bf}]{caption}` in your example document and it has an effect here., at least on the main figure caption. However, of course this does not have any effect on the sub-captions since the (ancient) `subfigure` package is not using these options. Only `subfig` and `subcaption` uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force solution: redefine `\thesubfigure` to use the colour you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{subfigure}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}\relax(\arabic{subfigure})}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}

        \begin{figure}
            \subfigure[Subfig 1]{
            }
            \hfil
            \subfigure[Subfig 2]{
            }
            \caption{Figure}
        \end{figure}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]